# List Level Design Permissions Possible for InfoPath work?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, permissions, office-365

I have main site "Home" where user A has read permissions at the site level.

I want user A to be able to design InfoPath forms for List 1 which is a list under site Home.  List 1 **does not** inherit permissions from Home site.

If I give user A Design permissions (or even Full) on List 1, she can not open InfoPath.  I'm forced to add the permission at the site level.

This doesn't work (Customize in Infopath is grayed out on List 1):

Site: **Home** (User A has read permissions at this level)

- **List 1** (User A has design permissions at this level)

This does work:

Site: **Home** (User A has design permissions at this level)

- **List 1** (User A has design permissions at this level)

Is there a way to give design permissions to a specific list without doing so at the site level?

Answer (score 0):

Your list is most likely still inheriting the site level permissions.  Click stop inheriting and the associated permissions groups and specifically give her the design capabilities for that list.

Comment: The list is not inheriting.  She has design permissions specifically for the list.  It's as if the InfoPath form is using the site level permissions rather than the list.

Comment: Has the form already been created or currently being worked on within InfoPath?

Comment: Yes, it's an existing infopath form for the list.  I can give her full permissions on this list and she is still not able to open it.  As soon as I give her the same permission at the site level that contains the list, she can open it.